# Adding a section-wise division on loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm using Canvas animation for image sequences on the scroll.

And this animation is working fine but I need to reduce the loading time because I'm using almost 884 images for this animation.

So, how can I add section-wise division in this loop? For example, the first 100 images will upload on start and after 5 seconds next 100 images will upload. So every after 5 seconds next 100 images will upload til 884 images.

```
const html = document.documentElement;
const canvas = document.getElementById("hero-lightpass");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

const frameCount = 884;
const currentFrame = index => (
  `compressed/${index.toString().padStart(9, 'web_0000')}.webp`
)

const preloadImages = () => {
  for (let i = 1; i < frameCount; i++) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = currentFrame(i);
  }
};

const img = new Image()
img.src = currentFrame(1);
canvas.width= window.innerWidth;
canvas.height=window.innerHeight;

img.onload=function(){
  scaleToFill(this);
}

function scaleToFill(img){
    var scale = Math.max(canvas.width / img.width, canvas.height / img.height);
    var x = (canvas.width / 2) - (img.width / 2) * scale;
    var y = (canvas.height / 2) - (img.height / 2) * scale;
    context.drawImage(img, x, y, img.width * scale, img.height * scale);
}

const updateImage = index => {
  img.src = currentFrame(index);
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {  
  const scrollTop = html.scrollTop;
  const maxScrollTop = html.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
  const scrollFraction = scrollTop / maxScrollTop;
  const frameIndex = Math.min(
    frameCount - 1,
    Math.ceil(scrollFraction * frameCount)
  );
  
  requestAnimationFrame(() => updateImage(frameIndex + 1))
});

preloadImages()
```

HTML

```
<canvas id="hero-lightpass"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with an interval ...
We add a new variable `loadedImages` and change the preloadImages

```
let loadedImages = 0
let loadedImages = 0
const frameCount = 884;
const currentFrame = index => (
  `compressed/${index.toString().padStart(9, 'web_0000')}.webp`
)

const preloadImages = () => {
  for (let i = loadedImages + 1; i < Math.min(loadedImages + 100, frameCount); i++) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = currentFrame(i);
    loadedImages++
  }
};

setInterval(preloadImages, 5000)
...
preloadImages()
```